# How to allow only one ToggleButton to be ON at a time in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, togglebutton

I have created a UserForm in excel 2010 and put 10 toggle button in it.When I run the form all of them can be ON (value = TRUE) but I want only one of them to be ON at the same time.Like below:

In A Class Module

```
Public WithEvents ToggleGroup As ToggleButton 

Private Sub ToggleGroup_click() 

' code

End Sub
```

In a UserForm

```
Dim Buttons() As New Class1 

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 

    Dim ToggleCount     As Integer 
    Dim Ctl             As Control 

    For Each Ctl In UserForm1.Controls 
        If TypeName(Ctl) = "ToggleButton" Then 
            ReDim Preserve Buttons(1 To ToggleCount) 
            Set Buttons(ToggleCount).ToggleGroup = Ctl 
        End If 
    Next Ctl 

End Sub
```

In a Module

```
Sub Form()
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: It has been a while, but in the preference for each option button, can't you set them all to the same group name, and Excel will do it for you automatically.

Comment: @ScottCraner how? could you provide me an example of that. tanx

Comment: The option button has the GroupName property, and joins the options if within a frame - the toggle buttons don't have this.  Found this site which explains it quite well:  http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=129:excel-userform-controls-checkbox-optionbutton-and-togglebutton&catid=79&Itemid=475

Comment: From my above comment looks like you need an Option button rather than a Toggle button.

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook I need toggle Button. tanx anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a Toggle button you could try this method:

Create a number of Toggle controls and use the **Tag** property to group your buttons.
The code below will then compare the name and tag of each control. All toggle buttons with the same tag will be made the opposite of the one that was clicked.

```
Private Sub Toggle1_Click()
    ToggleClick Me.ActiveControl
End Sub

Private Sub Toggle2_Click()
    ToggleClick Me.ActiveControl
End Sub

Private Sub Toggle3_Click()
    ToggleClick Me.ActiveControl
End Sub

Private Sub Toggle4_Click()
    ToggleClick Me.ActiveControl
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleClick(ClickedControl As Control)

    Dim Ctl As Control

    For Each Ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(Ctl) = "ToggleButton" Then
            If Ctl.Name <> ClickedControl.Name And Ctl.Tag = ClickedControl.Tag Then
                Ctl.Value = Not ClickedControl.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next Ctl

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Darren's answer works well except for one annoyance:  Excel (at least 2016) fires the "_Click" event when you set the value of the toggle control.  Annoying and not obvious (I'd go so far as to call it "errata" if not an outright bug), so I'd make the following additions:

1. Add the line `If Me.ToggleControlName.Value = False then Exit Sub` as the first line of each "_Click" event handler.
2. Add the condition `And Ctl.Value = True` to the ToggleClick subroutine's IF statement to prevent extra firings of the "_Click" event that aren't actually changing a toggle's value (if it's False, no need to set it to False, firing a useless _Click event handler).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get Darren's answer to work even with Erik's modification.  The below line kept throwing an error.

```
Ctl.Value = Not ClickedControl.Value
```

Below is the likely dumbed down version that worked for me for a simple system of 3 toggles.

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
    If Me.ToggleButton1.Value = False Then Exit Sub
    Me.ToggleButton2.Value = False
    Me.ToggleButton3.Value = False
End Sub
Private Sub ToggleButton2_Click()
    If Me.ToggleButton2.Value = False Then Exit Sub
    Me.ToggleButton1.Value = False
    Me.ToggleButton3.Value = False
End Sub
Private Sub ToggleButton3_Click()
    If Me.ToggleButton3.Value = False Then Exit Sub
    Me.ToggleButton1.Value = False
    Me.ToggleButton2.Value = False
End Sub
```

The only down side to this is that I can toggle off the currently active button so that none are active.  I would like it so that if you try to toggle off the active one, it stays active.  So one button is always on.

Comment: I actually like this. I don't need the extra restriction that one is always on. I just need two others to clear properly when one is clicked. I had made it so that Toggles B2 and B3 cleared when B1 was clicked, but then you still had to click B1 a second time (to get it to True state). This worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the Userform:

```
Dim Buttons() As New Class1

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ToggleCount     As Integer
    Dim Ctl             As Control

    For Each Ctl In UserForm1.Controls
        If TypeName(Ctl) = "ToggleButton" Then
            ToggleCount = ToggleCount + 1
            ReDim Preserve Buttons(1 To ToggleCount)
            Set Buttons(ToggleCount).ToggleGroup = Ctl
            Buttons(ToggleCount).CtlName = Ctl.Name
        End If
    Next Ctl

End Sub
```

In the Class Module:

```
Public WithEvents ToggleGroup As ToggleButton
Public CtlName As String

Private Sub ToggleGroup_click()

' code

End Sub

Private Sub ToggleGroup_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Dim Ctl             As Control

    For Each Ctl In UserForm1.Controls
        If TypeName(Ctl) = "ToggleButton" Then
            If Not Ctl.Name = CtlName Then
                Ctl.Value = False
            End If
        End If
    Next Ctl
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

'Try this in the Userform.

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
    If Me.ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
       Me.ToggleButton2.Value = Not (Me.ToggleButton1.Value)
    Else
       Me.ToggleButton1.Value = Not (Me.ToggleButton2.Value)
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton2_Click()
    If Me.ToggleButton2.Value = True Then
       Me.ToggleButton1.Value = Not (Me.ToggleButton2.Value)
    Else
       Me.ToggleButton2.Value = Not (Me.ToggleButton1.Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

'Works flawlesly for me.
'Cheers!